# How to update row from another row in oracle

Tags: oracle

In Oracle how to update ColA with another Col?
Is it possible to update ColA with Col B when I am using ColC as reference?
eg

*Table A

```
   ColA--|--ColB--|--ColC
X--------|--------|-----A               
Y--------|--------|-----B
Z--------|--------|-----C*
```

To Result

Table A

```
   ColA--|-- ColB  --|--ColC
---------|-----X-----|-----A
---------|-----Y-----|-----B
---------|-----Z-----|-----C

update TableA 
    set ColB = (select rowid 
                from inline_srms_main_tmp 
                where ColC = ColC);
```

How do update itself?

Comment: I think you are confusing rows with columns (at least your sample data is written that way).

Comment: Oh ya sorry my mistake

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something but to me it looks as if you want to put the value of `ColA` into `ColB` and "remove" the value from `ColA`

```
update tableA
   set colB = colA,
       colA = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the answer. I am thinking too much.
just

update TableA set ColB = ColA;